# i18n error message: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, json, shiny, shiny.i18n

I try to make a shiny dashboard with translations. I got the example from the Appsilon i18n hp.

Here is the JSON:

```
"languages": ["en", "pl", "hr"],
"translation": [
    {
        "en": "MtCars Dataset Explorer",
        "pl": "Eksplorator danych: MtCars",
        "hr": "Istraživanje MtCars Dataseta"
    },
    {
        "en": "Change language",
        "pl": "Wybierz język",
        "hr": "Promijeni jezik"
    },
    {
        "en": "Select",
        "pl": "Wybierz",
        "hr": "Odaberi"
    },
    {
        "en": "This is description of the plot.",
        "pl": "To jest opis obrazka.",
        "hr": "Ovo je opis grafikona."
    },
    {
        "en": "Scatter plot",
        "pl": "Wykres punktowy",
        "hr": "Dijagram raspršenja"
    },
    {
        "en": "X-Axis",
        "pl": "Oś X",
        "hr": "X os"
    },
    {
        "en": "Y-Axis",
        "pl": "Oś Y",
        "hr": "Y os"
    }
]
```

Here is the R code:

```
## load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(extrafont)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny.i18n)

## UI translation
i18n <- Translator$new(translation_json_path = "./trans1.json") # load translation file
i18n$set_translation_language("en") # set default language

ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny.i18n::usei18n(i18n),
  tags$div(
    style='float: right;',
    selectInput(
      inputId='selected_language',
      label=i18n$t('Change language'),
      choices = i18n$get_languages(),
      selected = i18n$get_key_translation()
    )
  ),
  titlePanel(i18n$t('MtCars Dataset Explorer'), windowTitle=NULL),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width=3,
      tags$h4(i18n$t('Select')),
      varSelectInput(
        inputId='x_select', 
        label=i18n$t('X-Axis'), 
        data=mtcars
      ),
      varSelectInput(
        inputId='y_select', 
        label=i18n$t('Y-Axis'),
        data=mtcars
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId='scatter'),
      tags$p(i18n$t('This is description of the plot.'))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$selected_language, {
    update_lang(session, input$selected_language)
  })
  
  output$scatter <- renderPlot({
    col1 <- sym(input$x_select)
    col2 <- sym(input$y_select)
    
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x= !! col1, y= !! col2)) + 
      geom_point(size=6) + 
      ggtitle(i18n$t('Scatter plot'))
  })
}

app <- shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Start the app with runApp(app) and I get the error message

> Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I only use "$" on the "input" and "i18n" variables. If I ask R:

> is.atomic(i18n)
> [1] FALSE

If I launch the code without the 7 selectInput lines, I do not get the error message.

What did I do wrong? What do I not get? Have there been changes in packages that I missed?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. It seems that going from version 0.2.0 to 0.3.0 may create this error depending on the order of arguments to the function update_lang().

With version 0.3.0 you should call the function update_lang() as follow :

```
update_lang(input$selected_language, session)
```

It seems that the order of the arguments called in your function is important with the version 0.3.0.

It's an issue on which they seem to be working on (see : https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.i18n/issues/111).

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the issue! Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you solved this already, but I ran into the same problem just now and found your post. There seems to be an update from version 0.2 to 0.3 that's causing this error. So far I am able to install an older version of shiny.i18n to make it work, try:

```
remotes::install_version("shiny.i18n", version = "0.2.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

corresponding CRAN repo: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/shiny.i18n/

Not sure if they'll be updating this in the future so v0.3 would work as well. But right now its the best workaround for now.

Comment: These are rather sub-optimal news for my dashboard at the moment. Anyway, thank you for the comment and the workaround.